# Why WCF Serialization

Tags: wcf, serialization, encoding

I am struggling to understand answer for one question.

- .net standard types are first converted to standard messages. This we call Serialization and will be done by one of the WCF serializer.
- Those standard messages are converted to stream of bytes . Its called encoding and done by Encoders and which encoder will do that is decided by binding we choose.

My Question is why this serialization is kept in between, Why.net objects are converted to steams of bytes directly by WCF run-time engine and transferred across.

Comment: @marc_s at least post this as an answer so the OP can mark it as such if it answers their question... it's not simply a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that connects a client and a server in WCF is the **contract** and the serialized XML format to exchange messages between the two parties.

WCF is an **interoperable** messaging service - it cannot rely on anything for the other party. WCF is **NOT** a ".NET object remoting" system or anything like that. WCF **cannot** rely on the other side of the communication being a **.NET** application, so therefore it cannot just exchange .NET objects.

WCF can talk to and serve data for anything - Ruby, Java - whatever. The smallest common denominator for this are serialized XML messages. Therefore, WCF will serialize your messages into a XML format (text or binary) and send them across the wire.

Comment: Hi marc, In WCF Service side first serialization is performed and .net object is converted to Messages and those messages then converted to sequence of bytes in the service side only. My question is why this serialization happen if at the end other party is going to get sequence of bytes.

Comment: As I tried to explain: since the WCF service can **only** rely on a XML-serialized message, it has to convert any .NET types into an interoperable XML message that **any client** - .NET or otherwise - can then read and interpret. How else would you get a Ruby client to understand your .NET data object??